# How do I use FFmpeg to convert .264 CCTV footage files to mp4 with h.264 codec?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, codec

I get the following error when I try to convert my test.264 file to mp4 using FFmpeg:

## Log

```
C:\ffmpeg\bin>ffplay -f h264 test.264
ffplay version N-29947-gcd244fa Copyright <c> 2003-2016 the Flimpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.3.0 <GCC>
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-freiOr --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmfx --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enab le-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrw henc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxays --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib 
  libavutil 55. 24.100 / 55. 24.100
  libavcodec       57.  41.102 / 57.  41.102
  libavformat      57.  36.100 / 57.  36.100
  libavdevice      57.   0.101 / 57.   0.101
  libavfilter       6.  45.100 / 6.   45.100
  libswscale        4.   1.100 / 4.    1.100
  libswresample     2.   0.101 / 2.    0.101
  libpostproc      54.   0.100 / 54.   0.100 
[11264 @ 00000000006ab840] missing picture in access unit with size 1073672
[h264 @ 00000000006ab840] No start code is found.
[h264 @ 00000000006ab840] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000000006a0Sa0] decoding for stream 0 failed
[h264 @ 00000000006a0Sa0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 <Video: h264, none>: unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, h264, from 'test.264':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264, none, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn
[h264 @ 0000000002c20aa0] No start code is found.
[h264 @ 0000000002c20aa0] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
    nan M-U:    nan fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0
```

[image: log]

## FFprobe description

```
  libauutil    55.   24.100 / 55.  24.100
  libaucodec   57.   41.102 / 57.  41.102
  libauformat  57.   36.100 / 57.  36.100
  libaudeuice  57.    0.101 / 57.   0.101
  libaufilter    6.  45.100 / 6.   45.100
  libswscale     4.   1.100 / 4.    1.100
  libswresample  2.   0.101 / 2.    0.101
  libpostproc   54.   0.100 / 54.   0.100 
[h264 @ 000000000061a600] Format h264 detected only with low score of 1, misdetection possible!
[h264 @ 000000000045bf20] missing picture in access unit with size 1073672
[h264 @ 000000000045bf20] No start code is found.
[h264 @ 000000000045bf20] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 000000000061a600] decoding for stream 0 failed
[h264 @ 000000000061a600] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 <Uideo: h264, none>: unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, h264, from 'test.264':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264, none, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn 

C:\ffmpeg\bin>
```

[image: FFprobe description]

Any advice is highly appreciated. These videos are from CCTV

Comment: There was a H264 decoding bug fixed yesterday. In a day or two, download the latest nightly and try.

Comment: Next time please copy and paste all of the text instead of making images of some of the text.

Comment: Hi I have updated the version still I am receiving the same error, The file is a raw CCTV footage with a .exe player file which is not working.